# toggle class to element only in div below it

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, squarespace

This is for:

https://josh-unger-mzr3.squarespace.com

I have two nav folders with pages beneath them in the left nav.  The page titles inside the folder have the following css:

```
.main-nav .subnav ul {display:none;
transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;

}
.main-nav .subnav ul.expand {
display: block;
}
```

I have jquery to toggle the .expand class that will display the titles on click:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".main-nav li.folder").click(function(){
   $
$(".main-nav .subnav ul").toggleClass("expand");
 });
 });
   </script>
```

I'm looking to have only the folder of the element that is clicked display instead of all of the folders.

Thanks.

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] - remember to click TIDY before you save. You likely want to look at closest, next or prev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is performing the click function on all elements of the class .subnav.
You were almost at your goal. Instead of expanding(/toggling css) on all classes you must use $(this).

My example uses this and searches all ".subnav ul" of this and then toggles the css.

```
$(".main-nav li.folder").click(function(){
   $(this).find('.subnav ul').toggleClass("expand");
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated to your code, but not seeing anything happen when the top folder is clicked now. @MenuItem42

Comment: I added one more });       Working now. thank you @MenuItem42 !

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear, but you have only to replace binding of the click function. -- I also checked the result on your page and if you call at the right conditions `$(this).find('.subnav').toggle();` your subelements will dissapear and the Folder 2 will move up again.

Comment: The first solution was perfect.  Not sure when you had looked at the site, I tried something briefly that was different but have reverted to the direction you helped me with.  The only issue is that I'm looking to have the menu close back up(space included), after a different folder has been opened.  Right now the space that it could potentially take up is still there once a folder has been opened. @MenuItem42